# Algorithm to Horizontally flip a raw image in a byte array

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

How do I flip the image Horizontally when I am working with a byte array. I am having trouble finding the algorithm for doing this, all examples seem to suggest using established graphics libraries which I cannot use.

Comment: It depends on the file format (encoding) of your image. Is it a JPEG? a bitmap? a gif? A byte array is just a container, it does not say anything about the encoding of the image.

Comment: I have 16 bit gray-scale raw image which i want to flip...

Comment: The term ["raw image"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format) is ambiguous. What's the *exact* image format? What does its header look like?

Comment: file format ".raw" which is saved in a 1 dimensional array

Comment: I hate to say this, but ".raw" can contain many different formats, depending on the camera or software that created the file. Where do you get the file from? And what software do you use to open/display it? Does your raw file contain meta-information (width*height) or do you have to know this information from another source?

Comment: I see that [this issue has already been explained to you previously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142387/convert-16-bit-raw-image-to-bmp-in-c-sharp). Thus, I'm voting to close.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that clarifies things! You should be able to use a similar algorithm for horizontal flip. Do you understand how the vertical flip works? If yes, where are you stuck when trying to adapt it to a horizontal flip?

Answer (score 0):

i used WPF power to flip the image horizontally, hope this help

```
<Image Name="image" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="-1"/>
            <SkewTransform AngleY="0" AngleX="0"/>
            <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

```
public Window2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.ShowDialog();
    var localImage = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    localImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

    var byteArray = ImageToByteArray(localImage);
    var imageAgain = ByteArrayToImage(byteArray);

    var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
    imageSource.BeginInit();
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageAgain.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    imageSource.StreamSource = ms;
    imageSource.EndInit();

    image.Source = imageSource;
}
public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
public System.Drawing.Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn));
}
```